# Why isn't my SwingWorker working?

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

My SwingWorker doesn't seem to work. It outputs nothing into the textpanel and nothing into the console. It doesn't even execute the actual cmd command in the ProcessBuilder..

I have no clue why it won't work. Anyone seeing anything wrong in the code?

```
public class cmdExec extends SwingWorker<Integer, String> {

    private int status;

    private FormPanel formPanel = new FormPanel();
    private FooterBar footerBar = new FooterBar();
    private TextPanel textPanel = new TextPanel();

    public cmdExec() {
        textPanel.appendText((this.getState()).toString());
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground() {
        try {

            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
                "cmd.exe", "/c", "copy NUL createThis.txt"
            );
            pb.directory(new File(formPanel.workspaceDir.toString()));
            pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
            Process p = pb.start();
            String s;
            BufferedReader stdout = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            while((s = stdout.readLine()) != null && !isCancelled()) {
                publish(s);
            }
            if(!isCancelled()) {
                status = p.waitFor();
            }
            p.getInputStream().close();
            p.getOutputStream().close();
            p.getErrorStream().close();
            p.destroy();

        } catch(IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }

        return status;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> messages) {
        formPanel.okBtn.setText((this.getState()).toString());
        for(String message : messages) {
            textPanel.appendText(message + "\n");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        textPanel.appendText((this.getState()).toString() + " " + status);
        formPanel.okBtn.setEnabled(true);
        footerBar.progress.setIndeterminate(false);
        formPanel.disableList(false);
        formPanel.disableWorkspace(false);
    }

}
```

In my main class I just call a `cmdExec.execute();` for it to run, and I checked if it even can call it and it does. I checked it by adding a sysout to all the methods in my swingworker, and it did print them on the methods it's supposed to run.

Have I forgot something? I'm just getting blind by looking all over it again to try to see what I've missed.

Here's the code calling the SwingWorker class:

```
cmdExec cmdExec = new cmdExec();
cmdExec.execute();
```

This code is in a ActionListener on when a button is pressed.

After further research; I noticed that it's because of these 3 lines:

```
private FormPanel formPanel = new FormPanel();
private FooterBar footerBar = new FooterBar();
private TextPanel textPanel = new TextPanel();
```

But I really need to reach variables inside those classes. How can I do this and have it all working?

Comment: Can you post the code when you are executing your swingworker?

Comment: @Gatusko absolutely! I edited the main post. It seems like something's wrong in the actual swingworker class, since it succeeds calling it. Also, all code if you'd really like to dig in is on this github repo: https://github.com/condolent/USB3Installer

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I'd be careful when using a `BufferedReader`, some processes may not print a new line character.

Comment: Your main problem is, you're creating a bunch of new instance of classes/components which don't seem to have been added to any visible UI container

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this, do you mean that the classes don't seem to include a visible component? Because they do; textPanel is a big textpanel (obviously :)), formPanel is a collection of alot of components to the left of the window and footerBar has a progress bar. Question is how can I access the components in those classes in a way that work?

Comment: In your constructor you need to pass the values you want and add. Try to refactor your constructor of your SpringWorker then pass the values you want to be proceed and changed.

Comment: @Gatusko I'm not quite sure what you mean. I'm kind of new to Java. Could you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New Constructor

```
public cmdExec(FormPanel formPanel,FooterBar footerBar,TextPanel textPanel ) {
            textPanel.appendText((this.getState()).toString());
        }
```

and in runWorker() you pass the values that you want to be changed.

```
   cmdExec = new cmdExec(formPanel,footerPanel,textPanel);
   cmdExec.execute();
```

But as see in your code you need to add an `PropertyChangeListeners` see more in the documentation how to add a progress bar [Documentation of SwinWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)

Comment: But that only allows me to use the variables inside the cmdExec method, right? It won't let me use them in other methods in the class. Like the `doInBackground()` method, for example. Or am I just completely missing something?

Comment: EDIT: I realized I had to initialize the variables via `this.footerPanel = footerPanel;` for example. Thank you so much for your help! :)